# Prove a square is a pullback

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, pullback, epimorphisms

> Let $C$ an abelian category, and consider the following diagram:
> $$
>   \require{AMScd}
>   \begin{CD}
>     P
>     @> \beta_1 >>
>     A_1
>     \\
>     @V \beta_2 VV
>     @VV \alpha_1 V
>     \\
>     A_2
>     @> \alpha_2 >>
>     A \,
>   \end{CD}
> $$
> Prove that if $\alpha_1$ is an epimorphism, then the square is a pullback.

I'm stuck, any hint, please? :(

Comment: Without any hypothesis on $P$ or the other morphisms? This is certainly far from true.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false.
As a counterexample, we consider the following diagram in $\mathbf{Ab}$:
$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
    ℤ
    @>>>
    0
    \\
    @VVV
    @VVV
    \\
    0
    @>>>
    0
  \end{CD}
$$